# "Similar questions" prompt shows closed questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, similarity

When asking a question, a "Similar Questions" panel displays on the right hand side. This shows **closed questions**.

Is there a good reason for this?

Example: (sorry for the large image but I tried to draw a good arrow to make up)

[image: Similar/closed]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hinting that a question you're about to ask has been asked and closed. Hence, you should take a look at it - perhaps it's related / duplicate to the one you're asking.

Comment: I seen finding **duplicates** as the inportant reason to display closed questions.